# INSTR with Long String (Rich Text)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to run the below query in MS-Access 2013. This SQL works perfectly when the format for CL.DES is saved 'Short Text' but fails when I change this to 'Long Text -  Rich Text'

```
SELECT 
IIf(CL.DES = "ALL" And InStr(CL.Dest_Excl,"ABCD")=0,"TRUE",
IIf(InStr(CL.DES,"ABCD")<>0,"TRUE","FALSE")) AS DES_CHK,
CL.[REG_CODE], CL.DES
FROM CL;
```

Unfortunately I have to keep the format as Long Text since there are multiple rows with more than 255 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LIKE` operator with wildcards instead, it works for Long text.

```
IIf(CL.DES LIKE "*ABCD*","TRUE","FALSE")
```